# CUDA Thrust performance

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce, thrust

I have a `640*480` `vector` which contains a set of numbers, I wish to find the `min` and `max` number of each row of the vector.

```
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
        Begin = m_valBuffer.begin()  + (i*C);
        End = Begin+C;

        rMinmax= minmax_element(Begin, End);
     }
```

However this is extremely slow, is there any way I could speed this up?

- The current load on the GPU when running this is only 34% so there must be a way to improve this?

Comment: So you are wanting to do 640 reductions, each on only 480 elements, on the same pitched linear memory?

Comment: I want to do a minmax_element on 640 elements, 480 times. the loop above shifts the begin and end 640 elements each iteration.

Comment: This whole operation could be done in a single call of an only slightly modified version of the basic NVIDIA SDK shared memory reduction kernel. Do you absolutely **have** to do this with thrust?

Comment: If you are open to commercial software: http://wiki.accelereyes.com/wiki/libjacket/group__minmax.htm 

Before anyone accuses me of anything, yes I work there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This example](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/sum_rows.cu) shows how to compute the sum of each row using 
the `reduce_by_key` algorithm.  You can easily adapt that example to compute 
the min or max of each row.  To compute the min and max of each row 
simultaneously you'll need to use [this strategy](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/source/browse/examples/minmax.cu).  Specifically, 
you'll need to use a `transform_iterator` on the input data and convert each 
value `x` into a tuple `(x,x)` before applying the `minmax_binary_op` reduction operator.

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/extrema.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

// minmax_pair stores the minimum and maximum 
// values that have been encountered so far
template <typename T>
struct minmax_pair
{
  T min_val;
  T max_val;
};

// minmax_unary_op is a functor that takes in a value x and
// returns a minmax_pair whose minimum and maximum values
// are initialized to x.
template <typename T>
struct minmax_unary_op
  : public thrust::unary_function< T, minmax_pair<T> >
{
  __host__ __device__
  minmax_pair<T> operator()(const T& x) const
  {
    minmax_pair<T> result;
    result.min_val = x;
    result.max_val = x;
    return result;
  }
};

// minmax_binary_op is a functor that accepts two minmax_pair 
// structs and returns a new minmax_pair whose minimum and 
// maximum values are the min() and max() respectively of 
// the minimums and maximums of the input pairs
template <typename T>
struct minmax_binary_op
  : public thrust::binary_function< minmax_pair<T>,
                                    minmax_pair<T>,
                                    minmax_pair<T> >
{
  __host__ __device__
  minmax_pair<T> operator()(const minmax_pair<T>& x, const minmax_pair<T>& y) const 
  {
    minmax_pair<T> result;
    result.min_val = thrust::min(x.min_val, y.min_val);
    result.max_val = thrust::max(x.max_val, y.max_val);
    return result;
  }
};

// convert a linear index to a row index
template <typename T>
struct linear_index_to_row_index : public thrust::unary_function<T,T>
{
    T C; // number of columns

    __host__ __device__
    linear_index_to_row_index(T C) : C(C) {}

    __host__ __device__
    T operator()(T i)
    {
        return i / C;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    int R = 5;     // number of rows
    int C = 8;     // number of columns
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 99);

    // initialize data
    thrust::device_vector<int> array(R * C);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
        array[i] = dist(rng);

    // allocate storage for per-row results and indices
    thrust::device_vector< minmax_pair<int> > row_results(R);
    thrust::device_vector< int              > row_indices(R);

    // compute row sums by summing values with equal row indices
    thrust::reduce_by_key
      (thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(C)),
       thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0), linear_index_to_row_index<int>(C)) + (R*C),
       thrust::make_transform_iterator(array.begin(), minmax_unary_op<int>()),
       row_indices.begin(),
       row_results.begin(),
       thrust::equal_to<int>(),
       minmax_binary_op<int>());

    // print data 
    for(int i = 0; i < R; i++)
    {
      minmax_pair<int> result = row_results[i];
        std::cout << "[";
        for(int j = 0; j < C; j++)
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << array[i * C + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "] = " << "(" << result.min_val << "," << result.max_val << ")\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
[  0   8  60  89  96  18  51  39 ] = (0,96)
[ 26  74   8  56  58  80  59  51 ] = (8,80)
[ 87  99  72  96  29  42  89  65 ] = (29,99)
[ 90  96  16  85  90  29  93  41 ] = (16,96)
[ 30  51  39  78  68  54  59   9 ] = (9,78)
```

Comment: It's not quite clear to me how you do each row independently, but simultaneously, using that approach.  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: I added some code to show what I had in mind.  All I did was take the `sum_rows` example and changed the values argument (i.e. `array.begin()`) to a `transform_iterator` that expands `x` into a `minmax_pair` (essentially, a tuple).